# how to print all active httpd configuration parameters?

Tags: apache

E.g. I started apache with command

```
$ docker run -d --name a2 httpd httpd -X -DFOREGROUND -DFOO -DBAR
```

How to print all configuration parameters [passed](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/httpd.html) with `-D` ?

Expected output is

```
FOREGROUND
FOO
BAR
```

I tried to look on `apachectl`, following `DUMP_` commands

```
-t -D DUMP_VHOSTS  : show parsed vhost settings
-t -D DUMP_RUN_CFG : show parsed run settings
-t -D DUMP_MODULES : show all loaded modules 
-t -D DUMP_INCLUDES: show all included configuration files
```

But no one command can do it

Comment: Did you try `docker inspect <your_container>`?

Comment: For sure. It shows me `"Cmd": [ "sh",  "-c",  "/usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND $HTTPD_PARAMS"]`. That's why I'm looking for way of dumping configuration parameters.